# Access 2007 Concatinate fields based on field value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am currently working on a database that has a series of yes and no questions in the GUI. I want to create some functionality that checks the input value against the "correct" answer specified in the logic. If the input value does not equal the "correct" answer, I want this to be noted in a DIFFERENT table in a specific field. I want this field to keep track/concatinate all incorrect answers together.

I know how this would be down with a web db like php/mysql but I am new to access and VBA scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Recordsets or SQL Statements are probably what you would want here.  The just use an if statment to check if the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would check the input is like this:

```
    wrongAnswerConcatenation = "Questions incorrect: "
    answerEnteredByUser = me.textboxname.value
    if answerEnteredByUser = "Whatever you want correct answer to be" then
        'whatever you want to do for correct code.
    else
        wrongAnswerConcatenation = wrongAnswerConcatenation & me.textboxname.name & " "
    end if
```

So that is for getting the incorrect questions. This next code is to insert it into a table, make sure you have created a table before you do this.

```
    query = "insert into tablename(valuename) values(" & wrongAnswerConcatenation & ")"
    docmd.runsql query
```

This should help.